# it says that looper.prepare must be called

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am updating progress bar with the help of handler of MainActivity
but it gives the error :Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ozrl.png)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ProgressBar progressBar;
Handler handler;
Thread thread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    thread = new Thread(new MyThread());
    thread.start();
    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            progressBar.setProgress(msg.arg1);
        }
    };


}

class MyThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Message message = Message.obtain();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            message.arg1 = i;
            handler.sendMessage(message);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your background thread has no looper, so it cannot call Message.obtain()

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are updating your UI from a different thread. So what you should be doing is like call the update method on main ui thread

```
handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   // Do something on UiThread
                   // update progress
               }
          });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run progress bar only on Main Looper.
Add

```
    handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper()) {
.....
}
```

Should work.